# Нет эффекта от вызова метода фрагмента, добавленного в активити

Tags: java, android, activity, android-fragment

Есть layout-файл, выступающий в качестве контейнера:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.test.test.MainActivity">
</FrameLayout>
```

Также есть java-класс, в котором идёт вызов метода из другого класса:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    List fragList;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Иницилизация второго java-класса
        fragList = (List) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frameLayout);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        //Вызов метода из другого класса
        fragList.enterBackButton();
    }
}
```

Наконец, имеется класс, который должен обрабатывать метод из первого класса (MainActivity):

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class List extends android.support.v4.app.ListFragment
{
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1, adapter2, adapter3;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context)
    {
        super.onAttach(context);
        //Инициализация адаптеров
        adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.test1));
        adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.test2));
        adapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.test3));
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        //Установка начального адаптера
        setListAdapter(adapter1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        //При выборе пункта списка адаптер меняется на другой
        if (getListAdapter() == adapter1)
        {
            switch (position)
            {
                case 0:
                    setListAdapter(adapter2);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    break;
            }
        }
        else if (getListAdapter() == adapter2)
        {
            switch (position)
            {
                case 0:
                    setListAdapter(adapter3);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    //Этот метод должен заменить onBackPressed(), объявленный в другом классе
    public void enterBackButton ()
    {
        if (getListAdapter() == adapter2)
        {
            setListAdapter(adapter1);
        }
        else if (getListAdapter() == adapter3)
        {
            setListAdapter(adapter2);
        }
    }
}
```

При запуске приложения должен появиться список, однако этого не происходит. Кроме того, при нажатии на кнопку "назад", программа завершается с ошибкой NPE.

Comment: Не понимаю, как и почему это должно работать ..

Comment: сожгите этот код и никому не показываете)))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это уже 3-ий, на моей памяти, ваш вопрос по одной и той же теме с одной и той же изначальной ошибкой. В третий раз повторяю:

> Фрагмент, объявленный, но не добавленный в активити не сможет работать со своей внутренней размектой, т.к. её не загрузил, т.к. не был в активити добавлен.

Вам надо:

1. Не добавлять фрагмент в разметку в разметке. Делайте это в коде через FragmentManager
2. Через FragmentManager же его и находите в разметке и именно на таким образом полученном фрагменте вызывайте нужные методы.

---

**UPD_0:**

Т.к. вы не добавили фрагмент до поиска оного он и получается равным `null`

Так что проверяйте на `null` найденный фрагмент и добавляйте его, если он не нашёлся.

```
fragList = (List) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frameLayout);
if(fragList == null)
{
    fragList = new List();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frameLayout, fragList).commit();
}
```

Comment: Через разметку тоже пойдет, только ссылку на фрагмента нужно получить через FragmentManager

Comment: @MrFirst, фрагмент в разметке влечёт за собой кучу багов. Например, при `replace` другим фрагментом фрагмент в разметке не исчезнет и будет виден за добавленным, если у него фон прозрачный.

Comment: Это нельзя назвать багом. Спорить не буду, и так и так правильно. Однако же фрагмент из разметки сам востанавливает свое состояние при перевороте activity, итд, тоесть нет нужды ручками атачить/детачить

Comment: @MrFirst, ну, ради единообразия подхода, я предпочитаю просто проверять через `FM` на `null` содержимое контейнера и добавлять, если шо. А так, единожды добавленный через `add` фрагмент вполне успешно восстанавливается при пересоздании активити

Comment: @MrFirst, и багом я бы это таки назвал - всё же различное поведение для фрагмента в контейнере.

Comment: Прошлые вопросы были направлены на устранение ошибки Null. В этом же я пытался понять, почему статический вариант не подходит. Ответ я получил.

Вы советуете добавлять фрагмент динамически, через FragmentManager. В этом и вся проблема - как именно это делается? Я знаю только один вариант: http://www.startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/175-urok-105-android-3-fragments-dinamicheskaja-rabota.html

Именно такую реализацию вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: @Win_D да именно этот способ я и имею в виду. А ошибка главная ваша в том, что фрагмент потом получать надо через fragmentManager.findFragmentById а не чрез new List

Comment: Но в таком случае мне придётся создавать сотни классов и layout-файлов. В приложении будет множество списков и под каждый необходимо создавать свой класс и layout, чтобы затем через replace менять один список на другой. Неужели нет более эффективного подхода или я вас неправильно понимаю?

Comment: @Win_D, вы поняли полностью не правильно. Вы единожды добавили фрагмент в активити. далее вы через `fragmentManager.findFragmentById` получаете именно этот добавленный фрагмент. Далее вы вызываете к-л его метод и меняете адаптеры списка. Никаких сонмов классов и разметок не нужно)

Comment: Я от всей души благодарю вас за помощь и отзывчивость. Но разве есть способ установить id фрагмента в java-классе, а не в xml-файле как обычно, когда фрагмент добавляется статически?

Comment: @Win_D, если вы загляните в документацию, то увидите, что агрумент-ID, это `ID` контейнера, в коий помещён фрагмент. Т.е., в вашем случае, фрагмент будет находиться так: `List fragList = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.АЙДИШНИК_ЛИНЕАР_ЛЭЙАУТА_СОДЕРЖАЩЕГО_ФРАГМЕНТ);`

Comment: В том то и дело, что ещё до того, как я начал задавать глупые вопросы, я пытался реализовать такой подход. Однако тогда (как и сейчас) у меня выдавало ошибку: http://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=2df058c76f0f53f349d1779e3b291680 Если же перед getSupportFragmentManager дописать (List), то конфликта не возникает, но список не появляется. Тогда я не смог разобраться с этой проблемой, поэтому решил, что такой подход неправильный. Если реализация верна, то почему IDE это не устраивает?

Comment: @Win_D, нельзя получить доступ к фрагменту активити до его, активити, создания. Во время инициализации переменной класса активити ещё не отображается и в ней нема фрагментов. Вам этот код надо перенести в туда, где вам этот фрагмент нужен и когда он уже добавлен. В вашем случае - в `onBackPressed`. Именно там вам надо назначать переменной фрагмент, найденный в `FragmentManager`. И да, его надо скастовать к вашему типу. Т.е. поставить `(List)` перед `getSupport........`

Comment: Инициализировал в onCreate(), однако список всё равно не хочет отображаться. http://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=6d6260a83f337038024bc62399a237e3 При нажатии на кнопку "назад" вылетает ошибка NPE, которой не нравится строка с вызовом метода из другого класса. P. S. при инициализации в onBackPressed() - ситуация полностью аналогичная

Comment: @Win_D, не хватает контекста вашей ошибки. Вы, может, не тот АйДи указали (у вас же Линеар был, вроде). Может вы фрагмент не добавили в активити до его поиска. Может у вас метод во фрагменте неверный, но при этом таки вызывается. Обновите вопрос. Представьте полную и актуальную информацию

Comment: Для удобства, LinearLayout я сменил на FrameLayout. P. S. Код и суть вопроса обновил.

Comment: @Win_D, см. обновлённый ответ.

Comment: @Win_D, и пересмотрите метод обновления адаптеров - скорее всего ни одно из условий никогда не будет выполнено. Добавьте вывод там в логи самого факта вызова метода  - так вы будете знать, что метод вызвался, и адаптеры не меняются по к-л другой причине, а не из-за невызвавшегося метода.

Comment: Я столько времени мучался над этим вопросом, и, наконец, всё заработало так, как надо. Спасибо за вашу отзывчивость и помощь новичкам. Если вы будете избираться в президенты, я обязательно проголосую за вас.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста) Фрагменты для новичков сложны, так что тут простительно ошибаться) А про ваш голос запомню - стать президентом в планах есть)))

Answer (score 1):

1. Вы неправильно сравниваете обьекты
   `getListAdapter() == adapter1` - так нельзя делать, в результате условия не выполняются
   `if -> else if`
   учите мат часть
2. Вы вызываете метод у инстанса который к вашей активити никакого отношения не имеет
   получайте фрагмент так:
   List listFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(id);